# Select all radio button in single click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Wrote some jQuery code to select all radiobuttons using single click. It's working on another page but not on this one. I am not sure why this is happening? Everything else is working but not selecting radio buttons

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!--This is Jquery to select the multiple radio button on click of button-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.noConflict();
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#selectE").click(function () {
                    $('input:radio[class=enroll]').each(function () {
                        $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    });
                });
                $("#selectR").click(function () {
                    $('input:radio[class=reject]').each(function () {
                        $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script src="staff_js/adm_enrol.js"></script> 
        <style>
            fieldset {
                border:2px solid black;
                border-radius:10px;
                padding:12px;
                position:relative;
            }
            legend {
                background: #FF9;
                border: solid 1px black;
                -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
                -moz-border-radius: 8px;
                border-radius: 8px;
                padding: 1px;
                margin:0px;
                font-size:18px;
            }
            .btn1 {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: 400;
                line-height: 1.42857143;
                text-align: center;
                white-space: nowrap;
                vertical-align: middle;
                -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
                touch-action: manipulation;
                cursor: pointer;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
                background-image: none;
                border: 1px solid transparent;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <fieldset>
            <legend><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Search</legend>
            <div class="row">
                <div class ="form-inline">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label for="acad_period">Academic Year</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select class="form-control input-sm"  name="acad_period" required>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <?php
                            include 'functions.php';
                            acad_year();
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label for="stuclass">Class</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select id = "stuclass" name="stuclass" class="form-control" required>
                            <option value="">Please select...</option>
                            <option value="13">XII</option>
                            <option value="12">XI</option>
                            <option value="11">X</option>
                            <option value="10">IX</option>
                            <option value="9">VIII</option>
                            <option value="8">VII</option>
                            <option value="7">VI</option>
                            <option value="6">V</option>
                            <option value="5">IV</option>
                            <option value="4">III</option>
                            <option value="3">II</option>
                            <option value="2">I</option>
                            <option value="1">KG/Prep</option>
                            <option value="Nurs">Nursery</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label for="appstatus">Application Status</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select id="appstatus" name="appstatus" class="form-control" required>
                            <option value="">Please select...</option>
                            <option value="N">New</option>
                            <option value="INTI">Invited for Interview</option>
                            <option value="INTE">Invited for Exam</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <br>
            <div style="text-align:right"; class="col-sm-12">
                <button id="srch" name="adm_search" value="Search" class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Search</button>
                <button name="adm_cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-danger" type="reset"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
                <br>
            </div>
        </fieldset>


        <br>
        <table id="app_enrolment" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive table-striped table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: top; width: 142x; text-align: left;"><i class="fa fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Result</th>
                    <th style="vertical-align: top;text-align: center;">Decision</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th style="vertical-align: top;text-align: center;">Student ID</th>
                    <th style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;">Name</th>
                    <th style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;">App.Status</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">App.Date</th>
                    <th style="vertical-align: top;">
                        <button name="app_eall" class="btn1 btn-info btn-md" value="Enroll All" id="selectE"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Enroll All</button> 
                        <button name="app_rall" class="btn1 btn-info btn-md" value="Reject All" id="selectR"></td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Reject All</button>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
```

I am unable to spot any error written in jQuery. Can someone please help?

Comment: I'm confused, you use `$.noConflict()` and then immediately use $?

Comment: I tried using jquery instead of $ but the result was still same

Answer (score 0):

First of all. There are no tags radio elements in your shown code.

The expression `input:radio[class=enroll]` is wrong. The attribute is called className not class. But why do you using this way. Just use a dot:`input.enroll:radio` instead of this attribute selector way.

But: you cannot select all radio buttons. That's a logic fail. Radio buttons are built to group them by name and select ONE per group. If you want to select all (or give the opportunity to select all) use checkboxes.